# FFMpeg convert only Audio and keep Video Setting with Subtitles, Metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, convert

I've been dealing with video conversion for a while now. I would like that the video is taken over 1zu1. Only the audio should be changed from DTS to AAC.

Unfortunately, the command does not accept the names of the audio stream and the subtitles.

They are then called title1, title2 and so on

ffmpeg -i Olympus.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 6 -c:s copy -map 0 -map_metadata 0 -movflags use_metadata_tags -map_chapters 0 Olympus2.mkv

I would be very grateful for a tip. Thanks very much